# Eclipse TFS plugin - how to tell it a file was moved?

Tags: eclipse, tfs, delete-file, file-rename

Is there a way to tell TFS that one or more files has been moved/renamed by another application (in our case, WebMethods 9) running in Eclipse?  We have to move/rename the files using WebMethods and **not** TFS, because WebMethods does a whole lot of automatic reference updating.  However, we haven't found a way to tell TFS "hey, trust me - I moved/renamed/deleted it outside of TFS".  Instead, it refuses to commit any changes back to the repository until the old file reappears.

We're working around this at the moment by creating dummy files with the old name and then deleting them *again* via TFS, but you have to agree that kinda sucks.  I'd be happy to treat a move/rename as a deletion of the old filename and creation of the new filename; I just don't want to have to fight TFS over it.

Eclipse: 3.6.1.M20100909-0800
TFS plugin: 11.0.0.201306181529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you use server workspaces or local workspaces.

In a *server workspace*, TFS requires that you inform the server for every change - to check out a file, rename, delete, etc.  This allows TFS to avoid scanning your disk for changes, which is beneficial for large repositories.  If you want to force a disk scan with Team Explorer Everywhere, because you may have made some changes outside of Eclipse, you can go to the Actions menu and select Detect Local Changes.

In a *local workspace*, TFS will examine your disk for changes every time you look at the pending change status.  So all you have to do is run `tf status` or click refresh in the Pending Changes View to see changes made to files outside of Eclipse.

If your workflow involves files changed outside your IDE frequently, I would strongly recommend using local workspaces, however this requires TEE 11.0 and TFS 2012 or better.

Comment: Unfortunately the TFS plugin we're using didn't come with a TF.EXE, but I'll give you the points since what you're saying makes sense  :)

Comment: I'm very familiar with the plug-in you're using.  :)  The cross-platform TEE CLC is a separate download on MSDN.  (If you installed the TFS plug-in for Eclipse from the update site you may not have seen it.)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661